# How can i create a categorized list like this

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I want to create a categorized list like this in the picture.

[image]

There are certain categories mentioned above like Microsoft .net framework and then it has further checkbox list.

Which control will be used to design this type of list?

Comment: winforms c#. although most controls are same in vb as well as c#

Comment: I recommend [UserControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a standard ListView.

Comment: it has some categories first mentioned and the further has some child options. I want a that think.

Comment: Those categories are groups.

Comment: yes you were right. it was standard ListView. was able to make it but was a little complicated. thanks